# Wordpress Search Form with Keyword Suggestion

Tags: plugin-development, search

Can we make this type of search form: http://infoproductdeals.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=79&page=1 ?

If you check there, after typing any word, it is showing some post with thumbnail. Can we make it using wordpress? If yes, please tell me the solution.

If we need to use any plugin, please name the plugin.

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you researched and tried? Please note that asking for plugin recommendations is considered not in scope here.

Comment: So what I will do? I want to show thumbnail, title and price within the dropdown